# Почему не срабатывает событие для новых элементов добавленных через submit?

Tags: javascript

Что только не перепробовал, не срабатывает событие на элементы которые добавлены через оброботчик submit.

```
  var list = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
  var items = list.children;
  const newItemForm = document.querySelector('.add-form');
  const newItemTitle = newItemForm.querySelector('.add-form-input');
  const taskTemplate = document.querySelector('#task-template').content;
  const newItemTemplate = taskTemplate.querySelector('.todo-list-item');

  var checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list-input');
  function toggleClassCompleted() {
      for (let i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
          items[i].classList.add('completed')
        } else {
          items[i].classList.remove('completed')
        }
    };
  };

  list.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.className != items) toggleClassCompleted();
  });

newItemForm.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const taskText = newItemTitle.value;
    const task = newItemTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    const taskDescription = task.querySelector('span');
    taskDescription.textContent = taskText;
    list.appendChild(task);
    newItemTitle.value = '';
    removingTaskOnButton(task);
  });
```

Интересно что на те элементы которые были все ок, а вот именно те которые добавил не работает, удаление кстати говоря работает, а добавление класса почему то нет, ощущение что коллекция items после submit не обновляется, заранее спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newItemForm.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    const taskText = newItemTitle.value;
    const task = newItemTemplate.cloneNode(true);
    const taskDescription = task.querySelector('span');
    taskDescription.textContent = taskText;
    list.appendChild(task);
    newItemTitle.value = '';
    removingTaskOnButton(task);

    checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list-input'); // !!!
});
```

---

```
if (evt.target.className != items)
```

Что здесь с чем сравнивается?

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Все получилось!!!!, по идее живая коллекция, с событием, честно не очень понял этот момент но взял из [статьи про Делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)